# How to ignore directories and certain patterns when supplying command-line arguments

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, file-io

I'm a newbie at Linux, and I am wondering if there's a 'one-liner' command that allows me to link everything in a directory to another directory, but ignoring subdirectories and certain wildcards from the source directory.

Let's be more specific...let's say I want to link everything in `/foo` to `/bar/tmp` as in...

`ln -s /foo/* /bar/tmp/.`

...but I want to:

- ignore any subdirectories in /foo
- ignore any files with the wildcard
  `runscript*`

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `find` like this

```
find /foo -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -name 'runscript*' -exec ln -s {} /bar/tmp/ \;
```

Comment: With GNU `ln`, you could use `-exec ln -s -t /bar/tmp {} +` using the target directory option (`-t`) and having `find` list conveniently large numbers of files on the command line in one go (the `+` notation).

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
cd /bar/tmp
find /foo -maxdepth 1 -a -type f -a \! -name 'runscript*' |
while read file; do
   ln -s "$file"
done
```

could do the trick.